# gRPC + Thread local issue

Tags: python-multithreading, werkzeug, grpc-python

Im building a grpc server with python and trying to have some thread local storage handled with werkzeug Local and LocalProxy, similar to what flask does.

The problem I'm facing is that, when I store some data in the local from a server interceptor, and then try to retrieve it from the servicer, the local is empty. The real problem is that for some reason, the interceptor runs in a different greenlet than the servicer, so it's impossible to share data across a request since the werkzeug.local.**storage** ends up with different keys for the data that is supposed to belong to the same request.

The same happens using python threading library, it looks like the interceptors are run from the main thread or a different thread from the servicers. Is there a workaround for this? I would have expected interceptors to run in the same thread, thus allowing for this sort of things.

```
# Define a global somewhere
from werkzeug.local import Local
local = Local()

# from an interceptor save something
local.message = "test msg"

# from the service access it
local.service_var = "test"
print local.message  # this throw a AttributeError

# print the content of local
print local.__storage__  # we have 2 entries in the storage, 2 different greenlets, but we are in the same request.
```

Answer (score 1):

the interceptor is indeed run on the serving thread which is different from the handling thread. The serving thread is in charge of serving servicers and intercept servicer handlers. After the servicer method handler is returned by the interceptors, the serving thread will submit it to the `thread_pool` at [_server.py#L525](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/python/grpcio/grpc/_server.py#L525):

```
# Take unary unary call as an example.
# The method_handler is the returned object from interceptor.
def _handle_unary_unary(rpc_event, state, method_handler, thread_pool):
    unary_request = _unary_request(rpc_event, state,
                                   method_handler.request_deserializer)
    return thread_pool.submit(_unary_response_in_pool, rpc_event, state,
                              method_handler.unary_unary, unary_request,
                              method_handler.request_deserializer,
                              method_handler.response_serializer)
```

As for workaround, I can only imagine passing a storage instance both to the interceptor and to servicer during initialization. After that, the storage can be used as a member variable.

```
class StorageServerInterceptor(grpc.ServerInterceptor):

    def __init__(self, storage):
        self._storage = storage

    def intercept_service(self, continuation, handler_call_details):
        key = ...
        value = ...
        self._storage.set(key, value)
        ...
        return continuation(handler_call_details)

class Storage(...StorageServicer):

    def __init__(self, storage):
        self._storage = storage

    ...Servicer Handlers...
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also wrap all the functions that will be called and set the threading local there, and return a new handler with the wrapped functions.

```
class MyInterceptor(grpc.ServerInterceptor):
  def wrap_handler(self, original_handler: grpc.RpcMethodHandler):
    if original_handler.unary_unary is not None:
        unary_unary = original_handler.unary_unary
        def wrapped_unary_unary(*args, **kwargs):
            threading.local().my_var = "hello"
            return unary_unary(*args, **kwargs)
        new_unary_unary = wrapped_unary_unary
    else:
        new_unary_unary = None

    ...
    # do this for all the combinations to make new_unary_stream, new_stream_unary, new_stream_stream

    
    new_handler = grpc.RpcMethodHandler()
    new_handler.request_streaming=original_handler.request_streaming
    new_handler.response_streaming=original_handler.response_streaming
    new_handler.request_deserializer=original_handler.request_deserializer
    new_handler.response_serializer=original_handler.response_serializer
    new_handler.unary_unary=new_unary_unary
    new_handler.unary_stream=new_unary_stream
    new_handler.stream_unary=new_stream_unary
    new_handler.stream_stream=new_stream_stream
    return new_handler

  def intercept_service(self, continuation, handler_call_details):
    return self.wrap_handler(continuation(handler_call_details))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).